# C# Call an instance method of parent class from a static method in a secondary static class

Tags: c#, static-methods, instance-variables

I have a public class B that inherits from a class A. Class B has access to an instance method TMA(). The method TMA() is implemented in class A, and I do not have access to A. I have a secondary static class C that implements a static method GetValue(). I need to access the instance method TMA() via the static GetValue() method. One complication is that the method GetValue() gets called many times.

```
public class B : A
{
    ...
}

public static class C
{
    public static double GetValue()
    {
        double result = 0;
        result = TMA(); // <--- I would like to do this but it does not work.
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have tried the following, and although it compiles, it crashes the program on execution. It may be that the program is creating too many instances of the class B, but I am not sure.

```
public static class C
{
    public static double GetValue()
    {
        B b = new B();
        double result = 0;
        result = b.TMA(); // <--- This did not work.
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have also tried accessing the instance method TMA() via object reference, but that did not work.

```
public static class C
{
    public static double GetValue(..., B ob)
    {
        double result = 0;
        result = ob.TMA(); // <--- This did not work.
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have read about the singleton pattern but I do not see how that could help me. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `did not work` means ? and by the way if `TMA` is an instance method and it is implemented in a non-static `class A`, there is no _magical_ way to access that method from `class C`, with only using the method name.

Comment: @Selman22: I am aware of that. Perhaps I should have said That will not work rather than did not work but the title of the question suggests that I am aware that instance methods cannot be called directly from static methods. Did not work means fails to compile.

Comment: @PBrenek: But you also said the third method "did not work" without explaining what you meant.

Comment: When you try to compile the third method, what is compiler's error message? Is it something like "TMA(...) is inaccessible due to its protection level"?

Comment: @Nuf: The error was: Cannot convert method group B to non-delegate type object. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: This error indicates that compiler thinks that "B" is not name of a class but rather name of some method or property. Could you verify, that "B" on the line where you get the error actually refers to class?

Comment: @Nuf: Thank you. Yes, B is a class, but I should point out that the method GetValue() is called from inside class B. What should be the calling syntax of this method in class B?

Comment: Probably something like this: double Result = C.GetValue(SomeInstanceOfClassB);

Comment: @Nuf: I have tried that approach but it crashes the program. Could the issue lie with the fact that the method GetValue() is receiving its parameters from var args = new object[] { arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, b}; where B b = new B();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59135/discussion-between-uf-and-pbrenek).

Answer (score 0):

Can you keep a static instance of `B` and just use it?

```
public static class C
{
    static B _theB = new B();

    public static double GetValue()
    {
        double result = 0;
        result = _theB.TMA(); 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @D Stanley: This approach compiles fine but when executing , the following error arises: Assertion Failed, at A.InputInitialize() and so on.

Comment: @PBrenek Without documenttaion or source for `A` it's impossible to tell what the root cause is.  Does `B` need more information that you're not providing?

Comment: @D Stanley: Not really. I can easily say double result = TMA(); inside class B and it compiles and executes as expected.

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `B` and `A` it's impossible to tell - what you've shown is not enough to diagnose the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

Wht exaactly is TMA doing?  Does it involve a particular A (or B) object?

Your third attempt would appear to be the most correct (depending on how you call) `GetValue()`. but it would be helpful to know exactly how it "did not work.".  (Did it crash? fail to compile? What was the error message?)

Comment: Did not work means failed to compile. The only time it compiled was with the instance of B as part of the code but the program crashed.

Comment: @PBrenek: but your third method is ALSO using an instance of B, and should compile.

Comment: It did not compile. The error I got was: Cannot convert method group B to non-delegate type object. Did you intend to invoke the method?